# How can I find the number of elements in hash of an arrayref?

Tags: perl, reference

```
$HoA{teletubbies} = [ "tinky winky", "dipsy", "laa-laa", "po" ];
```

How can I find the number of elements in this hash of arrayref(s)? It should return 4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, that's not hash of arrays.  That's hash of array references.  So you should dereference it with `@{...}` operator and (optionally) force scalar context to convert array into its length.

```
scalar @{$HoA{teletubbies}}
```

Comment: perldsc and perllol use the "hash of arrays", "array of arrays", etc. nomenclature. Anyone who writes `%HoA` probably has just read perldsc. I dislike it myself, but... it's too big to fight ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can get the size of an array in Perl by evaluating it in a scalar context.

E.g., you can do this explicitly like:

```
my $size = scalar @{$HoA{teletubbies}};
```

But you can also do it implicitly in this instance:

```
my $size = @{$HoA{teletubbies}};
```

And this being Perl, you could also do it like this:

```
my $size = $#{$HoA{teletubbies}} + 1;
```

(The `#` operator returns the last index of an array, so adding one to it will give you its size).

Comment: The last one is extra work and harder to read at a glance. In some cases, there's no real reason to search for "more ways" to do it.

Comment: The last one is also deprecated in 5.10.

Comment: What `$#` tells you depends on the value of `$[`.

Comment: So shouldn't it be: my $size = $#{$HoA{teletubbies}} - $[ + 1;

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: but don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the entire hash then just add a bit more to it:

```
my $size= 0 ;
foreach ( values %HoA ) { $size += @$_ }
```